# How can I compare a variable with more than one string?

Tags: php, string

How can I compare more than one string by using `==` and `or` in PHP:

```
if ($variable == "string-1" or "string-2") {
    // do something;
}
```

Is there any better or more formal method for comparing `$variable` with a bunch of strings?

Comment: `if( $variables == "string-1" ||  $variables ==  "string-2")`?

Comment: Your current code is wrong. You are currently doing this: if $var equals string1 or if string2 is true.

Comment: You can chain OR statements, or you could compile all the possible valid answers into an array and check to see if `$variables` is present `in_array()`

Comment: You can do, `if (in_array($variables, ['string-1', 'string-2'])) { ... }`

Comment: Worry about "correct" before you worry about "better".

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani That would depend on your use case.  Context matters, and you've provided none.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, I edited my post and I added more details to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$values = [
    'string-1',
    'string-2',
];

if (in_array($variables, $values, true)) {
    $variables = 'desired string';
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php